# how to get all the dates from previous months and dates before 15th of current month in mysql

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[Sql Column example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qgyem.png)

I Need help to write a query to get the move_in_date information from previous months and dates until 15th for the current month in mysql. I tried several ways but nothing seems to work. The datatype of the date column in my table is varchar.
I tried this query but it returns empty list
 `SELECT * FROM requisitions where day(Move_in_date) < 15`

(requisitions is my table name and move_in_date is my column name)

Thank you.

Comment: Add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM requisitions
WHERE
    Move_in_date < DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-16');
```

This says to include all dates which are strictly less than the 16th of the current month at midnight.  Hence, all days up to and including the 15th of the current month would be considered.

**Edit:**

Since you revealed to us that your dates are being stored as text in the format `'%d-%m-%Y'`, we will have to add an additional step to first convert your text strings to actual dates using `STR_TO_DATE`.  So now the query becomes:

```
SELECT *
FROM requisitions
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(Move_in_date, '%d-%m-%Y') < DATE_FORMAT(NOW() ,'%Y-%m-16');
```

In general you should avoid storing your dates as text, for the very reason you have seen above.  It makes querying your data much harder.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I tried this query. But I am not getting the previous months dates and the current month dates which is after 15th is also being displayed??

Comment: No, what you are describing should not be happening.  My query should only include dates less than the 16th of the current month.  Add sample data to your question.

Comment: Move_in_date                                                                                         
04-11-2017
05-11-2017
09-10-2017
15-11-2017
16-11-2017
17-11-2017
18-11-2017
20-11-2017

Comment: Your dates are in a non ISO format.  Let me update my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much for saving my day!! It works like a magic :)

Answer (score 1):

You query should be like,

```
SELECT *
FROM requisitions
WHERE MONTH(Move_in_date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE())
AND DAYOFMONTH(Move_in_date) < 15
```

Reference : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: This query would exclude all previous months.

Comment: Please check with only month condition, if it works then we have check DAYOFMONTH function. Might be date is not compare with number